# How do I correctly transform data from API to my class?

Tags: typescript

I am currently dealing with an API that returns everything as a string.
Here's what I get when querying the server:

```
{
    "id": "254", // string
    "firstName": "John",
    "isActive": "1" // can be 0 or 1. (bool)
    "venues": [
        { "id": "1", "label": "McNodals" },
        { "id": "2", "label": "Kurger Bing" }
    ]
}
```

I would like to transform it (cast it) to:

```
User {
    id: 254 // as a number
    firstName: "John" // it stays a string
    isActive: true // convert the 1 to bool
    venues: [
        Venue { id: 1, label: "McNodals" },
        Venue { id: 2, label: "Kurger Bing" }
    ]
}
```

I have found a way to do that but I dislike it and I would like to know if it's possible to do what I want (conversion on the fly) with directives.

I use this class that has a method, `deserialize`, that converts strings to ints and bools

```
export class Transformer {
    protected toInt = []
    protected toBool = []
    protected toObject = []

    deserialize(instanceData) {
        const keys = Object.keys(this)
        for (const key of keys) {
            if (instanceData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (this.toInt.indexOf(key) !== -1)
                    this[key] = parseInt(instanceData[key])
                else if (this.toBool.indexOf(key) !== -1)
                    this[key] = parseInt(instanceData[key]) !== 0
                else
                    this[key] = instanceData[key]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in all my classes I just have to extends Transformer and add a deserialize method

```
class User extends Transformer {
    public id: number = 0
    public firstName: string = ""
    public isActive: boolean = false
    public venues: Venue[] = []
    protected toInt = ['id']
    protected toBool = ['isActive']

    constructor(instanceData) {
        super()
        this.deserialize(instanceData)
    }

    deserialize(instanceData) {
        let data = instanceData
        super.deserialize(instanceData)
        this.venues = data.venues.map(v => new Venue(v))
    }
}

class Venue extends Transformer {
    public id: number = null
    public label: string
    protected toInt = ['id']

    constructor(instanceData) {
        super()
        this.deserialize(instanceData)
    }

    deserialize(instanceData) {
        super.deserialize(instanceData)
    }
}
```

I dislike having to write toInt and toBool everywhere.

Is there another way to achieve this using typescript ?

Thanks !

Comment: One obvious thing is that `Venue` shouldn't override methods that only call the inherited versions. But if this is **working code** that you would like feedback on, maybe see [codereview.se]; there isn't a specific problem here people can help fix.

Comment: Do not do this. You're wasting your time. Learn JavaScript

Comment: What do you mean Aluan Haddad? Not very helpful here.